# What is the maximum precision of the double and float datatypes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point, double, sqldatatypes

In MySQL, when you define a double or a float you define the precision like double(10,0). I also noticed you can define those types without a precision (which I assume means the maximum possible value). What is the maximum values for these datatypes and how would it be defined in sql (the (10,0) part of the datatype)?

Cheers

Comment: Documentation says what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a simple google search "mysql data types" you can get to the mySQL manual page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

This describes the maximum precision of a 4 byte single precision float as 23 and the maximum of a double precision 8 byte float as 53.

Comment: Ahh shiz, skimmed over that too quick! Thanks